# How do you upload your Web app to a production server?

Tags: python-3.x, iis, flask, wsgi, wfastcgi

I used [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8) to get Flask running on an IIS server, and the test app works great.

Now, I have developed a web app in Visual Studios 2013 and it works great on the localhost dev server.

When I transfer the files to the server I get the following errors for every package but Flask even though, I pip installed all the required packages on the server.. Note, I did change **init**.py to app.py to coincide with [the tutorial](https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8).

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\...\wfastcgi.py", line 779, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "D:\...\wfastcgi.py", line 621, in read_wsgi_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv('WSGI_HANDLER'))
  File "D:\...\wfastcgi.py", line 605, in get_wsgi_handler
    raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported%s' % (handler_name, last_tb))
ValueError: "app.app" could not be imported: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\...\wfastcgi.py", line 589, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])
  File ".\app.py", line 6, in <module>
    from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
ImportError: No module named 'flask_bootstrap'

StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

This error occurs with all the imports (except Flask), including flask_sqlalchemy, etc...

app.py (Using Python 3.5)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_scss import Scss
from config import DevConfig, BaseConfig
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_mail import Mail

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(BaseConfig)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
mail = Mail(app)

Bootstrap(app)
admin = Admin(app, name='Admin', template_mode='bootstrap3')

import AppName.views
```

My server folders are as such:

> ```
> /roothostingfolder
>     app.py
>     config.py
>     models.py
>     views.py
>     wfastcgi.py
>     web.config
>     /static
>         style.css
>     /templates
>         layout.html
>         index.html
>         login.html
>         ...
> ```

Do you know how to fix the error?

Comment: Something went wrong while installing your requirements.

Comment: I exported the requirements and `pip install -r requirements.txt` on the server in accordance with [Configure Python web apps for IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2017). Do you know of any tutorials for installing requirements?

Comment: Fixed! It was access to the requirements :/